# Having trouble creating a simple, dynamic and reusable PHP class for CRUD MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

so I started learning about OOP earlier this week, and want to create a simple, dynamic and reusable PHP class for CRUD with mysql. I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about this though. I would ideally like it to be copy-pasteable to any project.

So this is what I've got:

```
<?php

class CRUD{

    private $dbConn;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->dbConn = $this->connectToDb();

    }

    private function connectToDb(){

        $dbHost = 'localhost';
        $dbUsername = 'username';
        $dbPassword = 'password';
        $dbDatabase = 'database';

        $dbConn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbDatabase);

        if($dbConn -> connect_errno){
            die('Ingen forbindelse til database' . $dbConn -> connect_error);
        } else {
            $dbConn->set_charset('UTF8');
            return $dbConn;
        }

    }

    public function create($sql1){

        $this->dbConn -> query($sql1);

    }

    public function read($sql1){



    }

    public function update($sql1){

        $this->dbConn -> query($sql1);

    }

    public function delete($sql1){

        $this->dbConn -> query($sql1);

    }

}

?>
```

So the only way I've been able to come up with, is sending the SQL string in as a parameter, and then send it off to the database. That'll make the class usable for any query. I'm not sure it's the best way to go about it though?

I'm also not sure how I would do the read method to be copy-pasteable and if it's even possible, as I'll be printing out pre-styled HTML in the loop that runs through the database array.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why not use one of the many existing ORM frameworks instead of trying to roll your own?

Comment: Most modern 
[development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) come with a very robust ORM built-in. Unless you've tried all of these and found them inadequate you're wasting your time here. If you're trying to learn about how to write one, the best place to start is by using others and learning from their implementations.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good start, but you can split this class in two:

- DB: this class will only connect to the database
- Query: this class should have a instance of DB and just execute a query and return a result

There's a many ways to do that and will get better. You can also read about database abstraction(DAO):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer

and ORM:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping